# How to create Master pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create master pages using javascript. I created Javascript objects containing the html code then including the js the html files. The problem is that I cant inject css in the head of the html. the jquery append function is not working..

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Why in the name of Grizzly Adams would you want to include html pages as `.js` files ?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I suspect that, _"trying to create master pages **using javascript**"_ is supposed to read more like, _"trying to create master pages **which use javascript**"_. That... and, _"the jquery append function **is** working"_ is probably supposed to read, _"the jquery append function **is not** working"_. Without clarification, we're left with a lot of assumptions, though. Things look grim for this question.

Comment: @canon no need code, take it as a general case as if one want to create a "master page" with the help of js. Thanks for the correction and clarification.

Comment: @anchovyLegend no, I create vars containing HTML code, to inject them later in other html files using javascript. If you have any other way I'd be delighted :)

Comment: @EnderCode, yes, thats what AJAX is for. Send an ajax request to the server and prepare your html with a server side language such as php or asp then send a json_encoded response back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to inject CSS in the head for it to style your page. I think you can just include the <link> tag anywhere in the DOM and it should work.

However, if you must include it in the head, try this:

```
 function addcssfile(cssfile){
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('link');
    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    s.setAttribute('href', cssfile);
    head.appendChild(s);
 }
```

If you want to append just the CSS styles and properties, and not an actual CSS file, you can do this:

```
function addcss(css){
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('style');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    if (s.styleSheet) {   // IE
        s.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {                // the world
        s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    head.appendChild(s);
 }
```

Comment: I know you can inject the CSS elsewhere, but it's required from me to inject it in the head .. Thanks I'll try using your code and reply :)

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my question wasnt that clear.. I do have a js object that holds the head's html code(which also contains the style elements). I need to inject that var (holding the html head's code) in a new html file, specifically in the head...